# How do I view the version of Windows 10 on a remote computer?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10

From Windows Server 2012 R2, I'd like to view which workstations on my network have been updated to Windows 10 Versions 1511, 1607 and so on.

Just to clarify, 1511 and 1607 are the numbers that I'm looking for.

I don't want to sign in to each workstation (I might have 50 or more). I don't care so much about the Edition or Build Number unless those can somehow be used to easily determine the Version.

Comment: Are these Windows 10 computers domain members?

Comment: They are members of the domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this.

For each computer in Active Directory, its version of Windows is stored as an attribute named `operatingSystemVersion`.

[image]

You can query this from AD with a PowerShell command:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property operatingsystemversion | select name,operatingsystemversion
```

This will return the name and OS version of every computer in AD.

You could also query this information directly from your computers using the win32_operatingsystem WMI class, but the method above is easier.

Comment: Technically, that does answer my question. But it seems Windows has two different meanings for the word "version". The "version" I'm looking for is whether the OS is Version 1511 or 1607. That PowerShell command did not show it.

Comment: @James 10586 is the build number for 1511. 10240 was the original release. And for 1607, the build number is 14393.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: FWIW, winver.exe will show you both the version and build number for your local machine.

Comment: Do the values in AD get updated following at Windows 10 Feature update?